# Separate language and format locales in a Wicket app?

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-1.5

Our Wicket app needs separate UI language and number/date format locales (e.g. UI in english, Number and date format: German) per user.

If you set the session locale to say Locale.GERMAN, you get both german number and date format AND german resources (e.g. MyForm_de.properties).

We worked around this by setting the session locale to the number and date locale and then use a custom ComponentStringResourceLoader to load strings (return super.loadStringResource(clazz, key, language != null ? new Locale(language) : locale, style, variation)). However, it looks like strings are being cached because if I log on as different users, I start getting a mixture of languages.

Anyone know to control the caching (assuming that is causing the problem)? Note: I don't want to prevent caching (since that would presumably hurt performance). I guess I want to override the caching behavior so it works correctly with our custom resource loader.

Or is there a better approach altogether to solving this problem?

Here's the code we used for the custom StringResourceLoader.

```
ComponentStringResourceLoader myComponentStringResourceLoader = new ComponentStringResourceLoader() {
@Override
public String loadStringResource(Class<?> clazz, String key, Locale locale, String style, String variation) {
   return super.loadStringResource(clazz, key, getLoggedOnUser().getUILanguageLocale(), style, variation);
  }
};
getResourceSettings().getStringResourceLoaders().add(0, myComponentStringResourceLoader);
```

Here's the code to set the session locale (used for number and date formatting).

```
getSession().setLocale(getLoggedOnUser().getNumberAndDateLocale());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Session's locale for i18n of the labels and either override #getLocale() or #getConverter() for the components which should use the different locale for dates. I guess you talk about TextField which needs to render its value in German locale. If so, just create GermanTextField that always returns Locale.GERMAN in its #getLocale().

Comment: Thanks Martin - so if I understand you right, you're saying do it the other way around - set the user's UI language into the session locale (so I don't need to mess with resource loaders) and always use custom components which use the user's format locale where I need dates and formats. I'll have to try it, but I think you're right that this way will cause less trouble than the way I was trying.

Comment: OK - I reworked the code to use your suggestion and it works perfectly! Thanks again Martin!